# How to Get all values from a bitmap in Redis?

Tags: bitmap, redis

I have a bitmap which is stored across time frame. Say if a user request comes for a minute I will set the bit to 1. Now I want the full bitmap array in redis to know the user pattern.

I will do something like this. Where 5 and 10 are minutes.

```
setbit userpattern 5 1
setbit userpattern 10 1
```

I need something like this

```
getallbits user pattern 
0000100001 -> result
```

Do i have any commands to get all the bit values in redis. If not, is there any other possible way in redis to address this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GETRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/getrange) command with the caveat that you'll need to align your bits. Alternatively, there's the v3.2 and above [`BITFIELD`](http://antirez.com/news/103) command that is far more suitable (at least for up to 64 bit pattens atm).

Comment: I will use Getrange. But how to align the bits?. I have tried snippets of converting hex string to bit array. But it doesn't work. Any idea on this would be great.

Comment: Every character is a byte. When you GETRANGE you're basically reading in multiples of 8bits.

Comment: can you please add some example of redis cli to retrieve number of all set bits?
bitpos returns only first bit. Thanks

Comment: @user2737926 have you tried the [`BITCOUNT`](https://redis.io/commands/bitcount)